# The bogof offer or the offer bogof

Tags: phrase-meaning

> I think of the word "bread" .
>
> I find the phrase "advancing forward" fabulous.

In these I couldn’t understand why “bread” and “advancing forward”  is used after “phrase” and “word”. But as far as I have searched on the internet , we should say ;

> Buy one get one free offer

Instead of

> The offer ”buy one get one free”.

Why we should use this phrase before offer. Doesn’t it have the same structure as the phrases above?

Comment: Phrases like this are possible both before and after the noun depending on whether they are being used as adjectives. (Both of these sentences work for example: *The government issued “run, hide, tell” warnings.* *The warning “run, hide, tell” was issued by the government.*). I don’t think here is anything wrong with this sentence: *The offer “buy one get one free” is frequently used in those stores.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following example might offer some clarity. Consider the following phrases:

> The color red
>
> The red color

These are both grammatically correct, but they mean different things. "The color red" refers to the abstract idea of red, while "the red color" refers to a particular instance of something that is colored red.

> The color red symbolizes passion.
>
> The red color in blood is caused by the presence of hemoglobin.

Now in your examples, "the word 'bread'" refers to the word itself as an abstract idea, while "the buy one get one free offer" refers to some actual, particular offer at a store.

As an aside, I think you *could* correctly say "the offer 'buy one get one free'" in the right context, although it might not be the clearest choice of wording. For example,

> The offer "buy one get one free" was invented by Roman merchants in the second century CE.

In this situation I would probably write "the offer **of** 'buy one get one free'". This is because BOGOF is not the *name* of the offer exactly, it's more like a description of what the offer *is*.